# Creating a list with two (or more) different types?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I'm trying to determine what the best approach would be for my problem.

I need to display a list of items, kind of like a media library.

To get all the images data I use something like...

```
var images = dataSource.getImages();
```

This returns an array of objects.

To get all the audio data I use

```
var audio = anotherDataSource.getAudio()
```

This also returns an array of objects

The problem is the two objects are similar but have different property names e.g.

```
images[0].title
audio[0].trackTitle
```

Now I need a way of uniting these two arrays into something useful. What I am trying to avoid is having to too many conditions later on when dealing with the array e.g. sorting on title.

So I'm thinking I could create a new array of 'MediaItem' objects.
The constructor for MediaItem would handle the mapping of the similar properties to a common property.

Does anyone know if this is a recognised pattern or a pattern that would better suit my needs?

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to look around in http://underscorejs.org/ they will have something for it

Comment: no libraries, pure js

Comment: I think the approach you've suggested would work fine

Comment: I think then just looping through images and in that loop through audio to find the other would be the best approach, sorting it would make not much difference (because then you loop again through it) you may want to delete the found entries to optimize it

Comment: Your solution is good OOP if only the Audio item is related/linked to the Image Item. So to make sure your solution is the good one, please tell us why would your Audio and Image item needs to be in the same list, else there is no way we can confirm your solution has okay for what you are trying to do.